# How to request file permissions (to access pdf) in android 13

Tags: android, kotlin, pdf, permissions

If your app targets Android 13, you must request one or more new permissions instead of the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions.

```
`private lateinit var permissionsFileResultLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Array<String>>

fun requestFilePermissions(
        activity: Activity,
        mOnlyImageCheck: Boolean = true,
        mDocCheck: Boolean = false,
        callback: (fileUtils: FileData?) -> Unit
    ) {
        addImageCheck = mOnlyImageCheck
        docCheck = mDocCheck
        permissionSuccessCallback = callback
        permissionsFileResultLauncher.launch(
            arrayOf(
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            )
        )
    }

bindind.tvUploadDoc.setOnClickListener {
                fileUtils.requestFilePermissions(requireActivity(), false) { result ->
                    if (result == null) {
                        displayNeverAskAgainDialog(langData?.dialogsStrings?.storagePermissions.getSafe())
                    } else {
                        file = result.uri.let { uri ->
                            uri?.let {
                                fileUtils.getMimeType(requireContext(), uri = uri)?.let { it1 ->
                                    fileUtils.copyUriToFile(
                                        requireContext(),
                                        it,
                                        fileUtils.getFileNameFromUri(
                                            requireContext(), uri
                                        ),
                                        it1
                                    )
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        saveFile()
                    }
                }
            }`
```

I didn't find any information about this in the official documentation, but to be honest the documentation is focusing on media files only without any word about other file types (https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions)

Comment: `How to request file permissions (to access pdf) in android 13` One does not need a permission to let the user select a pdf file.

Comment: I am accessing external storage for selecting PDF from chooser
READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE which is working fine below than android 13 @blackapps

Comment: ????? One does not need a permission to let the user select a pdf file.

Comment: Have the same problem on Android 13.